# how to control max events in azure event hub listner batch

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am trying to implement an event hub received and listener interface is :

```
ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
```

Is there a way to control the max number of items in messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EventProcessorOptions.MaxBatchSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessoroptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventProcessorOptions_MaxBatchSize) is your friend.